# Make HTML table columns fixed width (and stretch to fit)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a calendar, and I've got it mostly working except I want to space it out a bit. I tried setting the table to `width: 210px` and `table-layout: fixed` so it'd work [like this](http://w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_table-layout&preval=fixed), but I can't seem to get it worked. Here  is the [jsFiddle;](http://jsfiddle.net/ELpS8/) when I set the width to 210px it just slides the table over. Fixed doesn't seem to do anything.

How can I set the column width to stretch to fit (and evenly spaced).

Comment: `table-layout: fixed` is the opposite of auto-width. Use CSS and set the width of each `td` to be `width: 14.29%;`

Comment: I just want it to stretch; I looked at the w3schools and this tutorial http://www.keyframe5.com/create-html-table-with-fixed-width-columns-with-css/ which both say you only need to add "table-layout: fixed" but my code looks identical to their's but without the effect

Comment: Is your `<body>` supposed to have `width: 210px`?

Comment: The body is suppose to have a width of 320px (iPhone theme); I set viewport to 320px but in the jsfiddle I just made a colored background so the positioning of the table was visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `display: inline-block` from the `table#cal` styling.

http://jsfiddle.net/ELpS8/1/